# From string to float android studio ESP32 Bluetooth connection

Tags: android, string, linechart

Hello Im reading data from a ESP32 through bluetooh interface, and then I use a linechart to graph that.

The problem is that Im having this exeption:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-61.87
-96.78"
    at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1306)
    at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1306)

    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:459)
    at jaodev.bluetoothreceivertransmitter.MainActivity$1.handleMessage(MainActivity.java:133)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

But I ca

```
 if(msg.what == MESSAGE_READ){
                String readMessage = null;
                try {
                    readMessage = new String((byte[]) msg.obj, "ASCII");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //mReadBuffer.setText(readMessage);
                if (readMessage != null&& !readMessage.isEmpty()) {

                    graficar((Float.parseFloat(readMessage))); // this function set data to linechart

                }
            }
```

Comment: Maybe the issue is the numbers on string? You have "-61.87
-96.78" with two signs, it can't convert or parsed